# Adding members to google group through google-apis

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-groups-api, google-groups-settings

Trying to find a way to add members to google group through google API but any search result always end up in using admin sdk for this. But for using Admin SDK it requires to sign up on Google workspace. Is there any other way to achieve the same without signing up on workspace through simple api call using OAuth.

Comment: Does the group exist already? Who owns it?

Answer (score 0):

- You are not a Google Workspace user but a Consumer (gmail) user
- You do not have access to the Admin SDK (apart from for publicly available methods)

**In this case, you can retrieve Google Groups programmatically is via [GroupsApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/groups-app) in Google Apps Script.**

However, this only allows you to get group / user information, not to create new users.

Unfortunately the latter is a service that is only available for Google Workspace users.